Find angles between columns of matrices in R
I' trying to generalize the computation of angles between two vectors in Angle between two vectors in R to the case of finding angles between all columns of a matrix X or between the columns of X and another matrix Y.
My attempt below fails, but I can't figure out why
len <- function(X) {
  if (!is.numeric(X)) stop("X must be numeric")
  if (is.vector(X)) X <- matrix(X, ncol=1)
  sqrt(colSums(X^2))
}
angle <- function(x, y, degree = TRUE) {
  if(missing(y)) y <- x
  if(is.vector(x) && is.atomic(x)) {
    theta <- acos(x %*% y / (len(x) * len(y)))
  }
  else {
    theta <- acos(t(x) %*% y / outer(len(x), len(y)))
  }
  if(degree) theta <- r2d(theta)
  theta
}

These seem to work:
> x <- c(-2,1)
> y <- c(1,1)
> angle(x, y) # degrees
         [,1]
[1,] 108.4349
> angle(x, y, degree = FALSE) # radians
         [,1]
[1,] 1.892547
> angle(x)    # for one arg case
             [,1]
[1,] 1.207418e-06

These fail or are wrong:
X <- matrix(
      c(1, 0, 1, 1, -2, 1),
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE)

Y <- matrix(
      c(1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0),
      ncol = 2,
      byrow = TRUE)

angle(X, Y)
angle(X)

Edit: I'm looking for a solution that handle all combinations of
X = {vector | matrix}
Y = {vector | matrix}
Edit
I need this to work within the angle function. I tried incorporate @ThomasIsCoding suggestion as below. Seems to work so far.
rad2deg <- function(rad) (rad * 180) / pi

angle <- function(x, y, degree = TRUE) {
  if(missing(y)) y <- x
  if(is.vector(x) && is.atomic(x)) {
    theta <- acos(x %*% y / (len(x) * len(y)))

    if(degree) theta <- rad2deg(theta)
    return(theta)
  }
  else {
    outer(
      asplit(x, 2),
      asplit(y, 2),
      Vectorize(\(x, y) angle(c(x), c(y), degree=degree))
    )  }
}


Update
If you want to make it faster, you can try (assuming you are working with matrices X and Y, where they have the same number of rows but might be different numbers of columns)
acos(crossprod(X, Y) / sqrt(outer(colSums(X^2), colSums(Y^2))))

Benchmark
Template borrowed from @jblood94's solution
library(collapse)
angle <- function(X, Y) {
    acos(sum(X * Y) / (sqrt(sum(X^2) * sum(Y^2))))
}
allAngle1 <- function(X, Y) {
    outer(
        asplit(X, 2),
        asplit(Y, 2),
        Vectorize(\(x, y) angle(c(x), c(y)))
    )
}

allAngle2 <- function(X, Y) {
    csx2 <- colSums(X^2)
    csy2 <- colSums(Y^2)
    setop(X, "/", sqrt(csx2), rowwise = TRUE)
    setop(Y, "*", 2 / sqrt(csy2), rowwise = TRUE)
    Z <- crossprod(X, Y)
    matrix(pmin(pi, pmax(0, 2 * atan(sqrt((2 - Z) / (2 + Z))))), ncol(X), ncol(Y))
}

allAngle3 <- function(X, Y) {
    acos(crossprod(X, Y) / sqrt(outer(colSums(X^2), colSums(Y^2))))
}

set.seed(0)
X <- matrix(rnorm(5e3), 50, 100)
Y <- matrix(rnorm(3e3), 50, 60)

microbenchmark(
    allAngle1(X, Y),
    allAngle2(X, Y),
    allAngle3(X, Y),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "equal"
)

and you will see
Unit: relative
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max
 allAngle1(X, Y) 78.123879 75.898247 77.880979 75.549746 99.305929 15.8612821
 allAngle2(X, Y)  1.254453  1.304197  1.211534  1.293789  1.329616  0.2408046
 allAngle3(X, Y)  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.0000000
 neval
   100
   100
   100


Older Solution
You can try outer + Vectorize like below, e.g.,
outer(
    asplit(X, 2),
    asplit(Y, 2),
    Vectorize(\(x, y) angle(c(x), c(y), FALSE))
)

which gives
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 1.570796 1.570796
[2,] 2.094395 2.094395


I guess you mean to handle the vector-by-vector case and recursively call itself if one/both are matrices?

@user101089 no, it is not recursion. I use outer to have all combinations of columns from X and Y, where the columns are achieved by asplit.

An efficient matrix multiplication approach inspired by this answer, which references the Julia package AngleBetweenVectors, based on notes by Prof. W. Kahan (see page 15). Kahan argues the half-angle returned by atan suffers much less from round-off error.
(UPDATE: further testing using Rmpfr did NOT confirm Kahan's claims about the atan formulation being superior to acos for precision for angles very close to 1 or pi, nor did I see an overall benefit to normalizing the vectors. The vectorized one-liner (acos(crossprod(X, Y)/sqrt(outer(colSums(X^2), colSums(Y^2))))) provided by @ThomasIsCoding seems to be at least as good.)
library(collapse) # for `setop`

allAngle2 <- function(X, Y) {
  csx2 <- colSums(X^2)
  csy2 <- colSums(Y^2)
  setop(X, "/", sqrt(csx2), rowwise = TRUE)
  setop(Y, "*", 2/sqrt(csy2), rowwise = TRUE)
  Z <- crossprod(X, Y)
  matrix(pmin(pi, pmax(0, 2*atan(sqrt((2 - Z)/(2 + Z))))), ncol(X), ncol(Y))
}

Compare timings against an outer+Vectorize approach (using a simplified version of the OPs function):
angle <- function(X, Y){
  acos(sum(X*Y)/(sqrt(sum(X^2)*sum(Y^2))))
}

allAngle1 <- function(X, Y) {
  outer(
    asplit(X, 2),
    asplit(Y, 2),
    Vectorize(\(x, y) angle(c(x), c(y)))
  )
}

X <- matrix(rnorm(5e3), 50, 100)
Y <- matrix(rnorm(3e3), 50, 60)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  allAngle1 = allAngle1(X, Y),
  allAngle2 = allAngle2(X, Y),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  allAngle1 18039.0 20376.25 24977.380 21913.30 30357.25 38858.8   100
#>  allAngle2   275.9   321.45   345.791   345.45   364.95   453.2   100


wow, that's really fast, cheers!

I think base R can achieve considerable speed performance as well, see my update

Your crossprod base option is probably the way to go. See the comment in the updated answer.
